# Do I need the google fit verification process

Tags: android, google-fit

I want to develop an app that can retrieve the data from Google Fit Api. To access the Google Fit Api and get the step count or heart rate do we need to go through the **app verification** process? 
Little confused on this process. Any input would be great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you dont need verification if its only for testing. But when you wanna have more users or just want to upload on google play to use api you need to go through verification process.